# QML PageStack , communication between Pages - return values

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I defined PageStack only on master page (a.qml) :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    width: units.gu(48)
    height: units.gu(60)
    PageStack {
        id: pageStack
        Page {
            id: page0
            title: i18n.tr("Root page")
            Button {
                objectName: "button1"
                color: "white"

                text: i18n.tr("Dictionary")

                onClicked: {
                    print("ChildA")
                    pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("ChildA.qml"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Child page (ChildA.qml) look like this :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

Page {
    id: page0
    title: i18n.tr("ChildA Page")
    Button {
        objectName: "button2"
        color: "white"

        text: i18n.tr("Start child SubChild1.qml")

        onClicked: {
            print("ChildA")
            pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("SubChild1.qml"))
        }
    }

    Button {
        objectName: "button3"
        color: "white"

        text: i18n.tr("Start child SubChild2.qml")

        onClicked: {
            print("ChildA")
            pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("SubChild2.qml"))
        }
    }

}
```

When closing SubChild2.qml or SubChild2.qml I need on ChildA.qml information if closed SubChild2.qml or closed SubChild2, and I need some return parameters from them.
How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare SubChild1 and SubChild2 statically in ChildA. Then append signal "pageClosed" to both of them with set of required parameters. Last step - add handler for these signals, for example

```
SubChild1 {
id: subChild1
...
onPageClosed: { /* my staff */ }
}
```

Comment: this does not seems to work : Cannot assign to non-existent property "onPageClosed"